# Django on SSH public IP

Tags: django

I have [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) installed on my SSH-server. But the SSH-server I'm working on, is not at my home. So the local ip-adres Django creates (127.0.0.0:8000) isn't available for me, I can't test my Django-apps graphicly.
What could be a Solution to get it work?

Djano has a command [*runserver*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver) that could set the IP-adres of the server like this:

```
django-admin.py runserver [IP]:[port]
```

But which IP I have to fill in there to make it work? The only IP I have is the IP of the SSH-server. Isn't it possible to fill in the IP-address of my webhost(but where I need to give in password etc)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Choose a publicly available port (say 8000), or redirect an existing web server to use the port you choose, and then start with

```
django-admin.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

**Edit**

If you happen not to control your available ports, you probably need to hook apache in front of your app. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/ for info on how to deliver your app with apache and mod_wsgi.

Comment: If you happen to control the entire machine, then just open that port in the firewall (iptables?). If you are on a typical webhost, you probably have apache running, so that's not the right way to do it. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/ for instructions.

Comment: Or is there a possibility to webbrowse from (the ip) of my ssh-server? So surfing on the internet with my SSH-server... (because I suppose on that way I could visit the local ip of the Django server)

Comment: you can try, if the port is open, the same address you use to log in (hostname) will probably be enough (with the correct port of course)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Putty with its tunnels. This program for windows, but I think you can find it for Linux if you use it. I used it to get access to my Postgres databse with pgAdmin with this [article](http://library.linode.com/databases/postgresql/pgadmin-windows). So you can use tunnel for 8000 port and program to get access to it on your local machine.